# What color should be use on the edge of isometric pixel art

Tags: pixel-art, isometric, outline

Is there a general rule to put outline/contour in isometric pixel art and what color should be used?

I know the inside can be outlined not by black but by the color used, but what about the outer part (the edge?), should it be black always or colored, and if colored, in what shade?

What is the general concesous?

Example shows edge of different colors used in edge, should it be always black,
should it be same color of the part near the edge, should it be darker shade of the color near the edge?

[image: Image made 100% by me]

[image: This example shows the edge colored depending of the color of the side]

Comment: I don't think there is a rule as such, have a look at different artists and experiment with what looks best - I like the eboy style https://shop.eboy.com/, really detailed and layered, but the elements standout clearly

Comment: It's called pixel ***art***. That means there is no hard rules and even if there is consensus, you should experiment with deviating from that consensus.